# How did the Romans salute the Republic?

Tags: ancient-rome, roman-republic

Are there any known phrases that were used by Romans to celebrate or cheer for the Republic?

I've searched for some phrases I came up with, like ***Ave Res Publica***, and some other derivatives I've gathered from google translator, which is not the most trustworthy Latin source. I just couldn't find a single occurrence of any such phrasing.

p.s.
***Ave Res Publica !!!***

Comment: Does *[Carthago delenda est](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carthago_delenda_est)* count?

Comment: @T.E.D. If we reduce the scope of "the Romans" down to that one *angry elder man* from 2nd century BCE, then, yes!

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

Other than "Ave", "Vivat" ([long] live) comes to mind.

I have also [found](https://www.forbes.com/sites/drsarahbond/2016/12/31/drink-and-live-among-the-good-ancient-toasts-to-welcome-the-new-year/#b404d3b63d3f) that in a toasting-cheering context, the proclamations "dii propitii!": (May the Gods be propitious!) and "Feliciter!" (be lucky, happy) were used.

The [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Res_publica) makes quite a good job of demonstrating that "res publica" was used to refer to  many different concepts:

- Tacitus did use it to signify the political system of the Republic, as opposed to imperial government.
- However in many contexts it simply meant "public affairs".
- It could also mean the State, even when under emperors.

So when uttering patriotic cheers, referencing the Roman Republic as a polity or nation, I think they would simply say **Roma** or **Popolus Romanus**.

When saluting the political system (for example to protest monarchy or tyranny) they might say "res publica", but I think it is more likely that they would prefer "**libertas**", "**mos maiorum**" (ancient custom), or some way of referencing the ancient constitution (the res publica wikipage claims without citations that they would mention the Twelve Tables in this role)

Comment: The *polity* of Rome was referred to as indicated on the eagles of the legions: "*Senatus Populusque Romanus*", and abbreviated "*SPQR*".